# how to do ' Store input from a text field in a PHP variable' in codeigniter?

Tags: html, codeigniter

My view:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Employee Id</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"   placeholder="Enter employee id"   name="empid">
                </div>
       </div>

           <div class="col-md-3">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label>Employee Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"   placeholder="Enter employee name"   name="empname">
                </div>
       </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="form-group">
                <label>Order Number</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control"   placeholder="Enter order number"   name="ordernumber" value="<?php echo $order_number;?>">
                </div></div>

                  <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="form-group">
                <label></label>
                <a onclick="myFunctionfirst()" class="form-control">Proceed to order Create</a>

                </div></div>
```

Once you click on 'proceed to order create' the second row is created. I want this to happen only when the first 3 fields in first row are filled.

And this is my controller:

```
public function index()
 {
    $empid = $_POST['empid'];

    If ($empid == ""){

        $this->load->model('invoice_model');
        $data['stat']= $this->invoice_model->get_stationary();

        $data['order_numbers']= $this->invoice_model->get_countnumber();
        $data['order_number']= $data['order_numbers'][0]->count+1;
        $data['page']='invoice/invoice_view';
        $this->load->view("template",$data);
     }
 }
```

And it's throwing an error undefined index empid

Comment: There are no client side or server side validations added. If you want all 3 to be filled, you should add validations of required. Also, in your <form> tag have you added method="post" ? In the controller, var_dump($_POST) to check if you get all the form values or not.

Answer (score 0):

first of all take form tag and put all your fields inside it.
then add "action" and method = "POST" attribute in form tag.you got this errro because there is no form tag in your HTML file.